# Set body background image to div background in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the Desktop version, I have a full-body background carousel using Javascript. It is working fine on the desktop. But when accessed through mobile, I need to display this carousel as the background of a `div` element, and I have the following script :

```
var slides = [
    'image-url-path-1',
    'image-url-path-2',
    'image-url-path-3',
    'image-url-path-4',
];

const img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        $('body').css("background-image", 'none');
        $('.campaign-left').css("background-image", "url('" + img.src + "')");
    } else {
        $('body').css("background-image", "url('" + img.src + "')");
        $('.campaign-left').css("background-image", 'none');
    }
}

img.src = slides[slides.length - 1];
```

Here the issue is, the background image is not appearing correctly in the `div` element. I mean it is not showing the complete background image. Only a part of the image can be seen. If I use the body background, full image is showing on the mobile screens. Is there any better method for doing this and solve the issue with images ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS media queries to detect the width of the screen which is a better method to detect if the device is mobile rather than user agent parsing.

For example

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-image: url(...);
  }
}
```

Or if you want to detect it form JS see:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_media_queries.asp

Comment: Actually, it is detecting the mobile screen correctly. But the issue is that it is not showing the complete background image.

Comment: Then use `background-size` CSS property

Answer (score 0):

if there is a background that you need to set it for body and a div in different screen size you can do it just with CSS.

add a class to the div that you want to set the background for it in mobile, use CSS media code as bellow to add the background to that div and the body

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .examplediv {
  Background-image:url('');
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 body{
  Background-image:url('');
 }
}
```